# How to use angular variables in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm new in angular Js.

Using angular variable in blade file, I'm getting the following error:

> Use of undefined constant count - assumed 'count' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\angularjsLaravel\resources\views\testing.blade.php)

My code,

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('employeeRecords', []);

(function (app) {
    "use strict";
    app.controller("EmployeesController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/employees'
        }).then(function (employees){

            $scope.employees = employees['data'];
        },function (error){
            console.log(error);
        });

        $scope.remaining = function () {
            var count = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.employees, function (employee) {
                count += employee.done ? 0 : 1;
            });
        }
    });
})(app);
```

blade.php

```
<div id="employee" ng-controller="EmployeesController">
    <h3 class="page-header">
        <small ng-if="remaining()">{{ count }}</small>
    </h3>
</div>
```

help me.

I'm looking forward to a solution.

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Getting this error: Use of undefined constant count - assumed 'count' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\angularjsLaravel\resources\views\testing.blade.php)

Comment: Blade and Angular use common syntax to show variable and that is the issue. So try to change the syntax of angular variable print. Blade file is looking for php variable not jquery .

Comment: Check angular reference for solution https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change Angular symbo when defining your Angular application module using Angular's `$interpolateProvider`

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

and then blade tags will be `{{ }}` and angular tags will be `<% %>` or anything you want

Comment: good luck to you... :)

Answer (score 9):

In theory, you would need to use

> @{{angular_variable}}

so the software won't take it as a const. In your case:

> @{{ count }}

Comment: If I use @{{ count }} it just displays a blank page.

Comment: This one should be the answer

Comment: you rock man! working perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

use **@{{angular_varialble}}** in blade file

```
<div id="employee" ng-controller="EmployeesController">
    <h3 class="page-header">
        <small ng-if="remaining()">@{{ count }}</small>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use @{{ count }} it just displays a blank page.